# C# ASP.Net MVC RegularExpressionAttribute validation: negative look-behind assertion: rendering '&lt;' instead of '<'

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

The following Attribute:

```
[RegularExpression(@"(?<!Unknown).*", ErrorMessage = "value cannot be Unknown")]
```

is rendered into the following html:

```
<select name="ChannelName" id="ChannelName" data-val-regex-pattern="(?&lt;!Unknown).*" data-val-regex="value cannot be Unknown" data-val="true">
```

This is obviously not what I wanted. Is there a way to write the Pattern property of the RegularExpressionAttribute so that it would be rendered correctly? Once I succeeded to solve quite similar problem with @Html.Raw(), but that was on the client-side.

Comment: If your regex were rendered (in)correctly as you describe, you'd have a page of broken HTML. Don't forget that `<` has special meaning in HTML. Any use other that as a tag delimiter **must** be escaped or in CDATA. What you are actually seeing is the correct rendering of your regex. Move along... there's no problem here.

Comment: You can put '<'s inside of html attributes.

Comment: please supply a reference to support your claim. I think you are wrong, but I'd be delighted to learn something new if you proved otherwise.

Comment: The documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(v=vs.98).aspx shows examples of encoded rendering of data-val-* attributes as well. I'd be surprised if it didn't work.

Comment: @jessehouwing: the link supports the claim that something else is wrong with my code. Still had no time to test it properly. Thank you.

Comment: @spender: I think that from what is written at http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attributes follows that only unquoted attributes may not include angle brackets.

Comment: I think the expression is wrong. Can you show us some examples of the inputs? Should it just disregard `Unknown`? If that's the case, then `^(?!Unknown)` should do.

Answer (score 0):

Why is it not what you want. &lt; is an escape sequence, when someone (the validation framework) read the attribute value they will see <

Comment: I have noticed the fact of pattern rendering because validation failed where it should have not; I certainly have to check it twice and thrice to get convinced that the pattern is to blame, and then I'll return with a statement. But since there are not several thousands of similar questions on the Net, looks like you're right and I have to search for another cause of failure.

Answer (score 0):

I think you regular expression is wrong. `(?<!Unknown).*` will succeed if there's any position in the text that doesn't have "Unknown" in front of it. I think you're looking for the following expression instead:

```
^(?!Unknown)
```

^ for the start of the string.

Then (?!Unknown) to prevent any string that starts with Unknown.